# angular service ready flag

Tags: angular, rxjs

i'm try to rewrite my angularJS app to angular2
so i got service which download i18n labels from different endpoints
and i need to know when all of data is ready.

in my angularJS components i can do like so

```js
vm.loading = true;
backend.ready.then(() => {
   loading = false;
   backend.getAlias('anyLabel')
})
```

so when loading === false i'm hide loader and can get aliases
But i can't figure out how i can do it with angular2 services and observables. Now i have something like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, zip, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';

export interface Alias {
    code: string;
    value: string;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackendService {
    private aliases: Alias[];
    private aliasDeclaration: Alias[];
    public ready: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.aliases = [];
        this.aliasDeclaration = [];
        this.ready = new Observable<boolean>();
    }

    private getAliases(): Observable<Alias[]> {
        return this.http.get<Alias[]>('/json/get-aliases?lang=ru');
    }

    private getDeclarations(): Observable<Alias[]> {
        return this.http.get<Alias[]>('/themes/backend/aliases-declaration.json');
    }

    public init(): void {
        zip(this.getAliases(), this.getDeclarations()).subscribe(([aliases, declarations]) => {
            this.aliases = aliases;
            this.aliasDeclaration = declarations;
            // i need to set ready = true here, but can't figure out how :)
        });
    }

    public getAlias(code): Alias {
        return this.aliases.find(alias => alias.code === code);
    }

    public getAliasDeclaration(code): Alias {
        return this.aliasDeclaration.find(alias => alias.code === code);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `behaviorSubject`

```
public ready= new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

to make ready emit

```
public init(): void {
        zip(this.getAliases(), this.getDeclarations()).subscribe(([aliases, declarations]) => {
            this.aliases = aliases;
            this.aliasDeclaration = declarations;
            // i need to set ready = true here, but can't figure out how :)
this.ready.next(true)

        });
    }
```

Comment: Looks pretty easy, thanks! I think i need to read some documentation

Comment: You may also consider make `private _ready = new BehaviorSubject(false); public ready = this._ready.asObservable();` - then you'll be safe that no one else can emit new value into _ready, but everybody can read it.

Answer (score 1):

There are various options but I would return an Observable from the `init` method although I prefer to add the suffix `Async` to my methods that return an observable or promise.

```
import { shareReplay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

```
public initAsync(): Observable<BackendService> {
    const merged = zip(this.getAliases(), this.getDeclarations()).pipe(shareReplay());

    merged.subscribe(([aliases, declarations]) => {
        this.aliases = aliases;
        this.aliasDeclaration = declarations;
    // i need to set ready = true here, but can't figure out how :)
    });
    return merged.pipe(map(() => this));
}
```

[`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) ensures that the same result is used. I also am returning the service itself from the Observable although that is not really necessary. It does make it easy for the subscriber to use the service that is now ready but return whatever you want.

Calling code

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.initAsync().subscribe(_ => /*do something*/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you looking to do with 'ready' if you just want to assign a value the you can use  `this.ready = Observable.of(true);` and add an import for Observable from `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: i'm just try to ensure ( in my components) that all my aliases is downloaded and component can use their, also show/hide loader and other things.